# One email address keeps subscribing to the same list over and over and over again. What can I do?

Tags: mailchimp

I've set up a mailing list, but one specific email address / user keeps subscribing to this specific list, over and over and over again. It's been going on for *7 months now*.

How can I blacklist them or somehow remove them from being able to sign up again?

They don't respond to email contacts either. At first I thought it was a bug with MailChimp / Slack (I use Slack for notifications) but now I'm frankly just tired of the whole thing, I don't want to see a "fake subscription" from a person who has already subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is from a bot. First, have you tried blocking that particular address?  That might be the easiest.

Other ideas:

- add a ReCAPTCHA to your signup form, it's available in MailChimp.
- use email list service integrated with MailChimp and Slack to identify bad email addresses, [Lusha](https://www.lusha.co/integrations) offers this.
- have you traced this address to identify any IP addresses? You can use this information to notify MailChimp about this email. They work with blacklists and perhaps this is an address that the blacklists have not identified yet.